# JQuery DataTables Object Keys as Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using JQuery DataTables, and have an object like:

```
{
  table_rows: {
     row1: {val: value1},
     row2: {val: value2},
     ...
     rown: {val: valuen}
  }
}
```

I need to tell DataTables to use the object keys of the `table_rows` object as rows, but it will not.  Every example I can find has `table_rows` as an array of objects, which would be have `table_rows [ {val: val1}, {val: val2} ...]`

Any ideas how to make the former work?

**EDIT: Added example:**

> http://jsfiddle.net/mbaranski/gh95yhqe/

Here is an example.

Comment: How about creating the array in required format from the given object.

Comment: I'm using the `ajax: { url: 'xyz', type: 'GET'}, columns: [ ???? ]` spec.  I cannot even figure out how to specify a value function with DataTables because they all want to pass 1 row at a time

Comment: do you have a minimal example that you can share on jsFiddle?

Comment: You need to convert object `table_rows` into array of objects before passing it to DataTables. Can you show expected table structure, i.e. what table columns do you expect to see?

Comment: See the edit, example is at: http://jsfiddle.net/mbaranski/gh95yhqe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own function to convert one format to another, for example:

```js
function formatData(data){
   var result = [];
   for(prop in data['indices']){
      if(data['indices'].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
         result.push({ 'indices': prop });
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh95yhqe/2/) for code and demonstration.

If you're using Ajax sourced data, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh95yhqe/3/) for an idea on how to use the function above.

Comment: That does indeed work, but I think you are missing an important point:  I'm using the `ajax: { url: 'xyz', type: 'GET'}, columns: [ ???? ]`, which does not work as you suggested.

Comment: I had hard coded the data in the fiddle because the "echo" stuff didn't work and I was in a bit of a hurry

Comment: @mikeb, updated answer with an example for Ajax-sourced data.

Comment: That is it, couldn't find that particular bit in the documentation.  Thank you very much.